Graphql-mesh How to forward query param on graphql source?
I wan't to forward the query string on graphql source. I have a _pid query param that is not part of the graphql query.

I created a plugin that extends context with this value or empty string and changed the endpoint to include it at the end.
export function useCopyQueryStringToContext(): Plugin<any> & MeshPlugin<any> {
  return {
    onParse({ extendContext, context }) {
      const url = new URL(context.request.url);
      extendContext({
        queryString: url.search || "",
      });
    },
  };
}

